# Classic ASP - Can I lose my nested loop in exchange for a join?

Tags: mysql, sql, asp-classic

I'm trying to optimise one of scripts. It's for a stock photo website and shows a large grid of images using a WHILE WEND loop, looping through my DB (MySQL) table of photos.

Inside this loop, I have another WHILE END loop that gets the names of the people inside each photo from my table of people.

My question is, can I lose this second WHILE WEND loop by adding a JOIN to my primary query?

My confusion comes from returning more than one person. I can't work out how to get the one or more names separated by commas, I just don't know. Maybe my script is fine as it is, but I'm sure it could be quicker without the nested loop, because at some point, I'm thinking about adding another query, that returns the first 5 keywords for each photo, and don't want to add another loop!

**SCREEN SHOT**

[image]

**MY PSUEDO CODE**

```
Set rsPhotos = Conn.Execute(" " _
& "SELECT photoID, setID, caption, dateCreated, dateUploaded " _
& "FROM photos ORDER BY dateCreated DESC;)"

While NOT rsPhotos.EOF
    Response.Write "<div>"
        Response.Write "<img src=""photo.jpg"">"
        Response.Write "<p>"
            people_str = ""
            Set rsPeople = Conn.Execute("SELECT p.person FROM photoPeople AS pp " _
            & "LEFT JOIN people AS p USING (personID) " _
            & "WHERE pp.photoID = "&rsPhotos.Fields("photoID")&" " _
            & "ORDER BY p.person ASC;")
            While NOT rsPeople.EOF
                people_str = people_str & ", " & rsPeople.Fields("person")
            rsPeople.MoveNext
            Wend
            rsPeople.Close
            Response.Write Mid(people_str,3)
        Response.Write "</p>"
    Response.Write "<div>"
rsPhotos.MoveNext
Wend

rsPhotos.Close
```

**DB SCHEMA**

```
PHOTOS tbl
photoID        |   INT 9
setID          |   INT 9
caption        |   VARCHAR2000
dateCreated    |   DATETIME
dateUploaded   |   DATETIME

PHOTOPEOPLE tbl
photoID        |   INT 9
personID       |   INT 7

PEOPLE tbl
personID       |   INT 7
person         |   VARCHAR 100
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it -

```
SELECT photos.photoID, photos.setID, photos.caption, photos.dateCreated, photos.dateUploaded, GROUP_CONCAT(p.person ORDER BY p.person ASC SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM photos
LEFT JOIN photoPeople AS pp
    ON photos.photoID = pp.photoID
LEFT JOIN people AS p
    ON pp.personID = p.personID
GROUP BY photos.photoID
ORDER BY dateCreated DESC
```

[GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: WOW, thanks a bunch! It works and performs much better than my previous method. I'm so glad you introduced GROUP_CONCAT to me, I have a lot of places for this. Also, thanks for paying attention to my ORDER BY person condition and adding a space and comma (, ) to the concat function separator. Great answer!

Comment: It is a very useful function but you need to be aware that the length of the string returned by GROUP_CONCAT is restricted by group_concat_max_len system variable.

Comment: I just checked: In my case, the default value should be sufficient enough (1024), as the most amount of people in one photo is 4. I'm using shared hosting so this variable can't be modified, so I'll bare this in mind for my other projects. Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to set it for the current session, even on shared hosting, using `SET @@session.group_concat_max_len=2048`

Comment: I swear I just read on somebody's blog that I couldn't, but MySQL docs says I can. Would I just run this as a separate query above my primary query: Conn.Execute("SET @@session......") ?